# Ffmpeg sbs 3d mkv to 3d baked into 2d video

Tags: ffmpeg, 3d, video-streaming, mkv, blu-ray

I have a couple of 3d blu-ray rips I'd like to stream to a tv that is not 3d compatible. I have a samsung smart tv with an app that I made to stream the video locally. I'm using ffmpeg on my backend to transcode video. I'm curoius to see if ffmpeg can take a 3d sbs mkv and bake the 3d elements into a 2d image. That way the stream is still 3d even on non-compatible devices.

Answer (score 0):

See the [stereo3d filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#stereo3d). Example to convert input video from side by side parallel to anaglyph yellow/blue dubois:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0 -vf stereo3d=sbsl:aybd -c:a copy output.mkv
```

See many examples at [FFmpeg Wiki: Stereoscopic](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Stereoscopic).

Comment: Do you know by chance if ffmpeg has support for MVC-3D?